# How to restore all my gitolites repos from a backup or another Gitolite server?

Tags: git, repository, restore, gitolite

I have a working Gitolite server right now and I backup every week.

Now I configured a new gitolite server, and I need to copy all the repos from the original server to the new one.

Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is copy the repo directories. Double check the permissions.

Comment: If I do that I´ll be able too keep the history too? I mean, the previous versions of the repo?

Comment: Tried this and got 'is not a git repository' (or similar) when trying to clone.